# Cant assign thread to local variable

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code in python:

```
class gateWay:
   def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = []
        self.var2 = {}
        self.currentThread = None

   def stateProcess(self, file):
     # some irrelevant code 
     self.currentThread = saltGatWayThread(self, file).start()
     return self.var1

   def stopRunning(self):
      self.currentThread.proc.stop()
```

In addition, here the source code of the saltGatWayThread:

```
class saltGatWayThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       # some irrelevant code
       self.proc = src.proc.Process1()
```

In addition, I have the following code in `src/proc/__init__.py`:

```
class Process1:
     def stop(self):
          # code to stop operation
```

In the console, I notice that self.currentThread is null.

My purpose is to save the thread in local variable, when start it. If I get an abort request, I apply 
     `stopRunning` function. This function, would take the saved thread and will do "clean" exit (finish the process of the tread and exit).

Why can't I save the thread, and use the structure of it later on?

Comment: Are you sure that `stateProcess` is being run?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, I run stateProcess and just after I run stopRunning

Comment: So you run `stopRunning` first, and then run `stateProcess` after that? But then `self.currentThread.proc.stop()` should raise `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'proc'`, since `currentThread` hasn't been initialized yet. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: @Kevin: No, I run stateProcess and then run stopRunning, so I know that when I call stopRunning, there is some value in self.currentThread (because stateProcess has been called before..)

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of code. When do you create instances of any of your classes?

Comment: So your threads are always run in a separate process from the main process? I don't see anything to imply that in the code you provided. Please provide a __runnable__ example of the code you're having issues with.

Answer (score 1):

invoke currentThread = saltGatWayThread() and then call .start(). currentThread does not contains thread instance because starts() method always returns nothing according to the threading.py source code. See source of C:\Python27\Lib\threading.py
    def start(self):
        """Start the thread's activity.

```
    It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the
    object's run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

    This method will raise a RuntimeError if called more than once on the
    same thread object.

    """
    if not self.__initialized:
        raise RuntimeError("thread.__init__() not called")
    if self.__started.is_set():
        raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
    if __debug__:
        self._note("%s.start(): starting thread", self)
    with _active_limbo_lock:
        _limbo[self] = self
    try:
        _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
    except Exception:
        with _active_limbo_lock:
            del _limbo[self]
        raise
    self.__started.wait()
```